# Delete or Update Swift Book in iBooks

Tags: macos, books

I had downloaded the Swift Book 4.0, it updated successfully on my iPhone but not on my Mac.

It did not even open the book. I followed the solution [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141135/swift-programming-language-ibook-not-updating), after I deleted the folder, I opened iBooks and it prompted me to update.

It then saved the updated book in `updates` folder but it still showed version 4 in iBooks. So I deleted the book again.

Now iBooks shows the book is updated, but it does not open. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:** Put mouse cursor on the book and it should highlight cloud symbol on top right corner. Download the book and it works.